# python ray - pyarrow.lib.ArrowInvalid: Maximum size exceeded (2GB)

Tags: python, pyarrow, ray, apache-arrow, apache-arrow-plasma

I am trying to load and process large files using ray.

I am using ray for the purpose of multiprocessing the files and improving the speed of the solution.

I keep running into this pyarrow error: `pyarrow.lib.ArrowInvalid: Maximum size exceeded (2GB)`. It seems to have something to do with the plasma object store.

I have tried to use huge_pages and mount it to the plasma store, increase the size of the ray object store on init.

Any help would be great.

Comment: What version are you using? This seems to be fixed in 0.15.0 https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-3762